# How to keep a WIX installer from creating a database if instance exists

Tags: sql-server, wix

I have an WIX installer that has a server install that consists of custom code and SQL Server. The project consists of the custom code installer and a bundle that includes the custom code with SQL Server.

In the bundle it checks to see if an instance name exists and if it does it doesn't install SQL Server.

```
<!-- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express -->
<Fragment>
    <?define SQLServer2012Link = http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/1/E/01E0D693-2B4F-4442-9713-27A796B327BD/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe ?>
    <?define InstanceName = "testinstance" ?>

    <util:RegistrySearch Id="SqlInstanceFound"    Variable="SqlInstanceFound64" Result="exists" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\$(var.InstanceName)" Win64="yes" />
    <util:RegistrySearch Id="SqlInstanceKeyFound" Variable="SqlInstanceFound32" Result="exists" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Value="$(var.InstanceName)" Win64="no" />


    <PackageGroup Id="PackageGroup_SQLServer2012">

        <!-- Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express for new instalation-->
        <ExePackage
                  Id="Package_SQLServer2012" DisplayName="Microsoft SQL Server 2012  Express SP2"
                  InstallCondition="NOT Installed AND InstallServer = 1" DetectCondition="SqlInstanceFound64 OR SqlInstanceFound32"
                  Name="Prerequisites\SQLEXPR_x86_ENU.exe"
                  DownloadUrl="$(var.SQLServer2012Link)"
                  Permanent="yes" PerMachine="yes" Vital="yes" Compressed="no"
                  InstallCommand="/QS /HIDECONSOLE /ACTION=Install /FEATURES=SQL /INSTANCENAME=$(var.InstanceName) /SQLCOLLATION=&quot;SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS&quot; /SECURITYMODE=SQL /SAPWD=&quot;password&quot; /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=1 /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=BUILTIN\Administrators /ADDCURRENTUSERASSQLADMIN=TRUE /SKIPRULES=RebootRequiredCheck /IAcceptSQLServerLicenseTerms">

            <RemotePayload
                        CertificatePublicKey="B78FE7F6917E1BC5F4A9C77BA3D555A0E807B9E0"
                        CertificateThumbprint="67B1757863E3EFF760EA9EBB02849AF07D3A8080"
                        Hash="94EAAFA2A4C976B107ED23502B9DE9FA0F87D2E5"
                        Description="Microsoft SQL Server 2012  Express SP2"
                        ProductName="Microsoft SQL Server 2012  Express SP2" Size="274628920" Version="11.0.5058.0" />
            <ExitCode Value ="3010" Behavior="success" />
        </ExePackage>
    </PackageGroup>
</Fragment>
```

In the custom code install it runs some sql scripts to create and populate the database.

```
<Component Id='SqlComponent' Guid='A60B1852-7C4B-402B-A619-EECA2893C5AC' KeyPath='yes'>
    <sql:SqlDatabase Id='SqlDatabase' Database='db' Server='(local)' Instance='testinstance' User='SQLUser' CreateOnInstall='yes' DropOnUninstall='no' ContinueOnError='no'/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateUsers" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateUsersSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="CreateBaseLineDb" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="CreateBaseLineDbSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="UpgradeDb" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="UpgradeDbSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/>
    <!-- sql:SqlScript Id="UpdateCustomPlayList" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="UpdateCustomPlayListSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/ -->
    <sql:SqlScript Id="RemoveOldContent" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="RemoveOldGuruContentSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="AddCompleteMedia" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="AddCompleteMediaSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="InstallContent" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="InstallGuruContentSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/>
    <sql:SqlScript Id="InstallFeaturedContent" ExecuteOnInstall="yes" BinaryKey="InstallFeaturedContentSql" SqlDb="SqlDatabase" User="SQLUser"/>
  </Component>
```

The problem is that even when the instance exists the custom code install still tries to create the database, which is already there.

How do I keep the sql scripts from running when the instance already exists?

Thanks,
Gary

UPDATE: I have added/modified the following code...

To the bundle...

```
<Variable Name="SQLInstalled" Type="numeric" bal:Overridable="yes" Value="0" Persisted="yes"/>

<MsiPackage Id="GuruServer" Cache="no" Compressed="$(var.Compressed)" InstallCondition="InstallServer = 1"
                    Description="Guru Server" DownloadUrl="$(var.GuruDownloadRepo)/{2}"
                    SourceFile="$(var.GuruServerInstall.TargetPath)"
                    Name="GuruTeach\$(var.GuruServerInstall.TargetFileName)">
            <MsiProperty Name="CHGFIREWALL" Value="[AddFirewallExceptions]"/>
            <MsiProperty Name="SQLINSTALLED" Value="[SQLInstalled]"/>
        </MsiPackage>
```

In the product I added the following condition to the component...

```
<Condition><![CDATA[SQLINSTALLED = 1]]></Condition>
```

What I don't know yet is how to modify the variable when SQL Server is installed.

Comment: Can you make your scripts idempotent? i.e. the SQL scripts themselves check `IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: In theory that should work if I rewrite each of the scripts but these scripts have been around for years and I prefer not to make changes to them if I don't have to.

Comment: I was thinking that if I could set a variable when/if SQL Server gets installed and check it in the install before running the scripts that would work. Just not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom action that checks for the instasnce .You  can `return;` if you dont want to execute the custom action  or set the result into the wix value

```
session["SQLINSTANCE"] = yourResult;
```

And in your wxs

```
  <Custom Action="DoSometh" After='InstallFinalize'>NOT Install AND  (<![CDATA[SQLINSTANCE<>"true"]]>)</Custom>
```